# Complex Query with another query in the condition

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements

I have two tables

accounts { acc_id, score,... }

friends { acc_id, friend_id }

I need query for selecting scores of all friends of John (for example)

Something like

SELECT (acc_id,score) FROM accounts WHERE (table friends contain entry (John,acc_id))

Is it possible to write such query ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to use a subquery.  It should look something like this:

```
    Select acc_id, score from accounts 
    where acc_id in (select acc_id where friend_id = 'John'sID');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using subquery:

```
Select acc_id, score from accounts 
where acc_id in (select acc_id from friends where friend_id = 'John'sID');
```

OR 
Using Join:

```
Select accounts.acc_id, score from accounts 
Left Join friends  using (acc_id)
where  friend_id = 'John'sID';
```